# How to assign each obs of a df to a specific label out of set of labels according to percentages of occurrence of these labels?

Tags: r

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(Var1=c("a","b", "c", "d"), Var2=c(seq(1,24)))
```

Assume I want to assign a label (say A, B & C) to each observation of `Var1` according to a percentage of occurrences of A, B, C in this dataset.

So far I tried to assign randomly the labels as follow:

```
labels <- sample(c("A", "B","C"), size=nrow(df), replace=T)
df <- cbind(df, labels)
```

Now I want let’s say A to occur in a proportion of 0.4, B of 0.1 and C of 0.5?

I’m quite new to R so any tips or hints are very welcome

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need exact proportions (as far as possible) or could you pass them as probabilities to `sample`?

Comment: Hi Roland, I would need both to be able to compare probabilities and occurence

Comment: That comment doesn't clarify this to me.